# objective-c frames

Tags: iphone, objective-c, macos

Why is this a bad assignment?

abstractionView.frame.origin.y = emptyFrameView.frame.origin.y;

The compiler complains... lvalue required as left operand of assignment

Comment: From Stack Overflow’s FAQ: ‘When you have decided which answer is the most helpful to you, mark it as the accepted answer by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer. This lets other people know that you have received a good answer to your question. Doing this is helpful because it shows other people that you’re getting value from the community. (If you don’t do this, people will often politely ask you to go back and accept answers for more of your questions!)’

Comment: possible duplicate of [Lvalue required as left operand of assignment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5527878/lvalue-required-as-left-operand-of-assignment)

Answer (score 0):

It's never been entirely clear to me why direct assignment to members of a `CGRect` structure doesn't work (apart from higher-level concerns with respect to needing to know when a member value changes for any `CGRect` that is being used to position a rendered element), but the way to work around this is to do something like the following:

```
CGRect original = abstractionView.frame;
abstractionView.frame = CGRectMake(original.origin.x, emptyFrameView.frame.origin.y, original.size.width, original.size.height);
```

It's kind of a pain, I know.  Maybe someone else can offer a better explanation about why this is necessary in the first place.

Comment: Try translating the dot notation into the corresponding getters and setters when applicable.

Comment: @Bavarious - Doesn't work with `CGRect` though, since it is a `struct` and does not/cannot have any accessor methods.

Comment: My point exactly. `a.frame.origin.y = n` is equivalent to `[a frame].origin.y = n`, whose left side is not an lvalue, hence why direct assignment to members of a `CGRect` structure doesn’t work in this case. It is an attempt at assigning a value to a member of a `CGRect` structure _returned_ by a method.