# String to CLLocation latitude and Longitude

Tags: iphone, objective-c, string, cllocation

I have two strings representing latitude and longitude like: "-56.6462520", and i want to assign then to a CLLocation object to compare to my current location.I tried the following code but i get errors only:

```
CLLocation * LocationAtual = [[CLLocation alloc]init];
LocationAtual.coordinate.latitude = @"-56.6462520";
LocationAtual.coordinate.longitude = @"-36.6462520";
```

and then compare the object with my actual location latitude and longitude. Any suggestions?

Comment: Objective-C convention is camelCase for var names.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you need to:

```
LocationAtual.coordinate.latitude = [@"-56.6462520" floatValue];
LocationAtual.coordinate.longitude = [@"-36.6462520" floatValue];
```

Comment: I got the point, i think the conversion is correct, but im getting this error: "Lvaule required as left operand of assignment"...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5527878/lvalue-required-as-left-operand-of-assignment

Comment: I cannot delete an accepted answer, but agree AmitP's answer is correct. My answer was along the lines of "you can't use a string as a number"

Comment: Expression is not assignable

Answer (score 109):

You cannot assign directly into *coordinate* - it is a readonly property of CLLocation.
Use the following instance method:

```
- (instancetype)initWithLatitude:(CLLocationDegrees)latitude
                       longitude:(CLLocationDegrees)longitude
```

example:

```
CLLocation *LocationAtual = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:-56.6462520 longitude:-36.6462520];
```

Comment: That's true, you can't assign to CLLocation attributes.

Answer (score 9):

Swift Answer for the lazy:

```
var LocationAtual: CLLocation = CLLocation(latitude: -56.6462520, longitude: -36.6462520)
```

Answer (score 1):

CLLocation coordinate is actually a read only value

```
    @property (nonatomic, readonly) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
```

So the best way to assign dummy data to coordinates is AMITp way

Answer (score 1):

lattitude and longitude are double values so need to be assigned this way.

```
CLLocation *LocationAtual=[[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:[[location objectForKey:@"latitude"] doubleValue] longitude:[[location objectForKey:@"longitude"] doubleValue]]
```