# How to fake the location in iOS simulator programatically

Tags: ios, geolocation, ios-simulator, cllocationmanager

I am trying to fake the location of my simulator programatically. I have seen other posts where they have asked to use .gpx files. But, I am doing the automation testing wherein I need to send my own lat/long values. Ultimately, my simulator needs to pick up the lat/long values that I have provided through the code.

Comment: Does this not work for you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7907734/string-to-cllocation-latitude-and-longitude

Comment: Using .gpx files is the only way. This option is in scheme edit.

Comment: Move all of your location getting code out into its own service (class) that implements a generic protocol. Then inject an instance of the protocol into any part of your app that needs it.  In test, inject a mock one -- this is called "dependency injection", if you want to research it.

Comment: @Ryan - you are right we got to use the .gpx file anyways

Answer (score 0):

I just found  a way to answer my question. I had to write an AppleScript to achieve the automation of the location. Something like this -->

tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Xcode"

tell menu bar 1
            tell menu bar item "Debug"
                tell menu "Debug"
                    tell menu item "Simulate Location"
                        click
                        tell menu "Simulate Location"
                            click menu item "Home"
                            delay 1
                        end tell
                    end tell
                end tell
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell